# Check permissions READ_CONTACTS in MIUI

Tags: android, android-permissions

I try to check permissions 
in my Manifest I set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Then in fragment I try to check

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
```

But I get only 0 despite of any state of permission in application properties in OS.
I checked in Android 4.4.4  MIUI 6.5.1
May be the reason in MIUI

I have got -1 if I try check permission which there isn't in Manifest, but I wanna know the switch state of the permission.

Thanx

Comment: You have to manually allow permission to read contacts in MIUI as the OS blocked reading of contacts by default.

Comment: did you get to solve the issue? thanks!

Comment: no i don't decide this problem it a bug of MIU

Answer (score 3):

Add this function to your code  and call checkUsagePermission() for READ_COntacts only in MIUI

```
private boolean checkUsagePermission() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        int mode = 0;
        mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow("android:read_contacts", android.os.Process.myUid(), getPackageName());
        boolean granted = mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;
        if (!granted) {
           //write your code here for accept that permission 
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

0 means PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

You get zero in Android version below Android 6 because permissions are already provided before the app is installed. If you install this app in a phone running on Android Version 6 or greater then it will return -1 which means PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED as Android 6 does not ask for permissions before the app is installed rather it asks for permissions at runtime.

Hence write code like this -

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

This way your app will ask for permission only if you don't have the permission and it will only happen on Android 6 and above. Below Android 6 you will already have the permission.

**Edit** :  It seems MIUI provided run time permissions well before Google introduced them in Android 6. So the problem you are facing is specific to MIUI. If you use any other device other than MIUI below Android 6 then you won't get the option to deny selective permissions. You either provide all permissions or cancel the installation. So you app will work fine on all other devices.

Comment: I know that 0 means PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED. But I get 0 when permission switched off in application permissions too.  When I install app Android ask me to permit  READ_CONTACTS. But I wanna  exclude user wrong doing.

Comment: In android 6 and below(Your MIUI incuded), once the permission has been provided, you cannot revoke it. That is why it will always be 0. I don't know how you are switching off permissions in MIUI. You can only deny permissions from Settings in Android 6 devices.

Comment: After install the app Android ask me "Are you shure to permit to READ CONTACTS". If I say NO, this permission is switched off. The same result I can got from OS GUI if I switched off this permission. As the result. I can't recognise if user was doing like this, and can't say to him "App can't work correctly"

Comment: Yes i just checked with a MIUI. It seems MIUI provided run time permissions well before Google introduced them in Android 6. So the problem you are facing is specific to MIUI. If you use any other device other than MIUI below Android 6 then you won't get the option to deny selective permissions. You either provide all permissions or cancel the installation. So you app will work fine on all other devices. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested with MI 4W with MIUI 7 6.3.31 Beta.

I am facing the same checkSelfPermission returned true error as you did when I request for Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS only.

Even if I have denied a request for Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, it will set "Deny" to Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS. Checking for both permissions will return true.

Although I have denied, checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) returns true, and occasionally MIUI will pop up a message to inform users that the access to CONTACTS is denied.

Here are my actual permissions:
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)

PermissionUtil:

```
public static boolean hasSelfPermission(Context context, String permission) {
    // Below Android M all permissions are granted at install time and are already available.
    if (!isMNC()) {
        return true;
    }
        return context.checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    public static boolean isMNC() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
    }
```

Test Code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "READ_CONTACTS: " + PermissionUtil.hasSelfPermission(TestActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS));
Log.d(TAG, "WRITE_CONTACTS: " + PermissionUtil.hasSelfPermission(TestActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS));
Log.d(TAG, "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: " + PermissionUtil.hasSelfPermission(TestActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION));
Log.d(TAG, "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION: " + PermissionUtil.hasSelfPermission(TestActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION));
Log.d(TAG, "CAMERA: " + PermissionUtil.hasSelfPermission(TestActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA));
Log.d(TAG, "RECORD_AUDIO: " + PermissionUtil.hasSelfPermission(TestActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO));
Log.d(TAG, "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: " + PermissionUtil.hasSelfPermission(TestActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
Log.d(TAG, "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: " + PermissionUtil.hasSelfPermission(TestActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
```

All permissions were denied in the App Settings.

Results:

```
04-01 13:16:54.967 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: READ_CONTACTS: true
04-01 13:16:54.967 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: WRITE_CONTACTS: true
04-01 13:16:54.967 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: false
04-01 13:16:54.968 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION: false
04-01 13:16:54.968 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: CAMERA: false
04-01 13:16:54.969 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: RECORD_AUDIO: false
04-01 13:16:54.969 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: false
04-01 13:16:54.970 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: false
```

I have conducted test on Nexus 5 and denied all permissions.

Results:

```
04-01 13:16:54.967 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: READ_CONTACTS: false
04-01 13:16:54.967 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: WRITE_CONTACTS: false
04-01 13:16:54.967 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: false
04-01 13:16:54.968 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION: false
04-01 13:16:54.968 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: CAMERA: false
04-01 13:16:54.969 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: RECORD_AUDIO: false
04-01 13:16:54.969 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: false
04-01 13:16:54.970 25481-25481/com.test.test D/TestActivity: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: false
```

Concluded this to be a bug with MIUI 7 6.3.31 Beta.

Comment: // Below Android M all permissions are granted at install time and are already available.// 
It is not true for all devices. For example on Redmi prime 2 which is android Lollipop 5.1.1 . As you have said all permission are already granted but in this customized android user can explicity deny the permission then your code still returns true which is not true. You have to check separately for MIUI devices below Marshmallow. 
Please check all the case first, it might mislead the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#PERMISSION_GRANTED

> 0 stands for PERMISSION_GRANTED

I have created a sample app on **[Github](https://github.com/rathodchintan/RuntimePermissionDemo)** to demonstrate permission model.

#### Check Version

```
/**
* Check build version
*/
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
    displayContacts();
}else {
    requestContactPermission();
}
```

#### Check for Permission

```
private void requestContactPermission() {

    int hasContactPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);

    if(hasContactPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, READ_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Contact Permission is already granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        displayContacts();
    }
}
```

Here, `READ_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE` is any integer value

#### Handle Permission

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode){
        case READ_CONTACT_REQUEST_CODE:

            // Check if the only required permission has been granted
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Camera permission has been granted, preview can be displayed
                Log.i("Permission", "Contact permission has now been granted. Showing result.");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Contact Permission is Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                displayContacts();

            } else {
                Log.i("Permission", "Contact permission was NOT granted.");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Permission is not Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking SDK version is redundant. You can directly check if permission is given or not. This way you'll be doing 2 checks unnecessarily.

Comment: it's will never happened for me because every time I've got 0   
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == 0 and hasContactPermission == 0
S o I'll see "Contact Permission is already granted", but in's not true becase I switched off manualy  this permission at app properties and this desision doesn't recognise this

Comment: @user5546244 can you please tell me which device you are using and what version? Because after granting permission 1 time, it will be persist for next onward. You can go to settings and then disable permission to ask user again.

Comment: @user5546244 have you tried to implement my demo of Github?

Comment: XIAOMI MI4 MUIUI 6.5.1

Comment: Yes. I setted up your example and get the same result. After install app and click any button Android ask me to get permission. I've answered NO, after that I've restarted app and try again click this button, Anroid newer ask me again to permit READ_CONTACTS and doing nothing. App doesn't recognise that permission wasn't permitted manually.

I have the same behavior of my app. If the user one time said NO, I can't  recognise it

Comment: @user5546244 i have a concern. Please check your application in other device also. Are you getting same result? Them something is wrong, if not then its device specific issue.