# How to check permission for sms in miui phones

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, user-permissions, runtime-permissions

I heard that miui phone also ask for permission as marshmallow so I created some code for it.

It works well on other phones but when I tested it on MIUI devices it **returns 0 wether I accept permission or denied permission.**

Below I put my code which check permission

```
if ( android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M )
{
    checkAndRequestPermissions(); // this method first check for permisison if not granted then call ActivityCompact.checkSelfPermisison(context,permisison);
}
else
{
    int permission = PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    Log.d("Permission status","Status"+permission);
}
```

Comment: In [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35148218/4391450) you can see that MIUI's OS provide his own permission management sooner than android. So there is problem with those. But I don't see any help for it ...

Comment: AxelH i had a button which send sms on click and progressbar is visible until sms delivered. but in miui if i denied sms permisison still progressbar is visible so i want to check if permission is not granted then not send sms and not show progressbar. so help with some suggestions .

Comment: I get your problem ... but as I said, this seems to be a problem on MIUI because they provide a different system in the past leading to some bug. Don't know if there is a solution, never work on those devices (don't even know them...) but with that information, You can try to do some research based on that.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer

Comment: Try this it may be work stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Comment: RobbyPatel thanks for your answer but i already tried it not work and it may be some problem with MI phones.

Answer (score 3):

please add this code and call checkUsagePermission function for checking read sms permission in miui above marshmallow

```
private boolean checkUsagePermission() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
        int mode = 0;
        mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow("android:read_sms", android.os.Process.myUid(), getPackageName());
        boolean granted = mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED;
        if (!granted) {
            //write your code for accept that permission
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the sample code for marshmallow and above versions:

public static class Utility {
        public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context) {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

this is a method that checks for permission for reading external storage. please refer the code and manipulate accordingly. Hope this helps you out.

also add this code in onCreate method

boolean result = Utility.checkPermission(MainActivity.this);

Comment: Ravish Sharma my code works good on other devices but not works only in MIUI devices it always returns 0 for both accept and denied permission i put same thing in  checkAndRequestPermissions() method

Comment: thats why i give you code u can check this may this code works on MIUI devices too

Comment: It always return true weather i accept or denied permission.

Comment: i had a button which send sms on click and progressbar is visible until sms delivered. but in miui if i denied sms permisison still progressbar is visible so i want to check if permission is not granted then not send sms and not show progressbar.